# When use ReadOnlyProperty and when Binding

Tags: javafx

There are two kinds of read-only observable value: `javafx.beans.binding.Binding` and `javafx.beans.propety.ReadOnlyProperty`.

What is their difference in practical use? I may listen to both of them.

What interface should I implement if I want to create read-only observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are interfaces, so you cannot instantiate either. In practice, you will either use a concrete implementation of one of them (e.g. `StringProperty`, which is an implementation of `ReadOnlyProperty`, among other things, or a subclass of `StringBinding`, which is an implementation of `Binding`), or you will call a method that returns one. When calling a method, the type is, of course, dictated by the return type of the method.

The functional difference is that a property wraps a value that typically is implemented directly by being stored in a variable, whereas a binding has a dependency on one or more other values (and may just be computed "on-the-fly" as required).

For example:

```
IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5); // a property, stores its value directly
IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10); // another property

// the sum of x and y, observable, but computed when required:
IntegerBinding sum = new IntegerBinding() {
    { super.bind(x, y); }
    @Override
    public int computeValue() {
        return x.get() + y.get() ;
    }
};
```